# GCM Notification setAutoCancel(true) not working in Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am displaying a notification with this code, but setAutoCancel(true) is not working because when i press on the notification to open the app, the notification is still on the notifications bar and i must delete it manually with the finger gesture for deleting notifications or with the clear all button from notifications bar.

**It works fine in android 4.4.2 device, but it does not work in my nexus 7 with 5.1.1**

What is wrong?

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(GCMListenerService.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    String appName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);       

    int width;
    int height;
    if (Util.checkAndroidVersionUpperOrEqualThan(11)){      
        width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_width); 
        height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_height);
    }else{
        width = 64;
        height = 64;
    }

    image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setLargeIcon(image)
    .setContentTitle(appName)
    .setContentText(message)
    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: Use `.setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)` with all other option with setAutocancel and others.

Comment: Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE is for API Level 21... it is not possible to solve this with a lower compile api level?

Comment: i tryed using the value of the constant but does not work... .setCategory("msg")

Comment: You were asking about 5.1.1 which is API 22 obviously higher and do not instead of "msg" use `Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE`

Comment: i tryed with .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE) and did not work.... :/

Answer (score 0):

You must set Notification flag with .setOngoing(true)

```
   val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
   builder.setOngoing(true)
   notification = builder.build()
   notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT
```